# IE 11 and chrome not recognizing check boxes types

Tags: javascript

we have a cold fusion application that uses the java script below to check for required items on the page, but for some reason on IE 11 and chrome, the types are not being recognized. So we added a default type which will now recognize the types but still doesn't recognize checboxes. What are the new types for IE 11 and chrome or what is wrong here.

```
function setActionChanged(chngName, curRow) {

var curObject='';
var origObject='';
var objType='';
var nameArray = new Array(1);
    nameArray[0] = "A";
    nameArray[1] = "D";
    nameArray[2] = "C";
    nameArray[3] = "S";
    nameArray[4] = "D;
    nameArray[5] = "SID";
    nameArray[6] = "TID";
    nameArray[7] = "STID";
    nameArray[8] = "RID";
    nameArray[9] = "Cts";

document.getElementById(chngName).value = false;

for (var i=0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {

    curObject=nameArray[i]+curRow;

    origObject="orig"+nameArray[i]+curRow;
    //Find out what type of object this is -- text, checkbox, etc.
    if (document.getElementById(curObject) == '[object]') {
        objType=document.getElementById(curObject).type;
    } else {

        objType=document.getElementById(curObject); 
    }

    switch(objType) {
        case "textarea":


            if (document.getElementById(curObject).value != document.getElementById(origObject).value) {

                document.getElementById(chngName).value = true;

                document.getElementById('ActionFormChanged').value = true;

                return true
            }
            break;
        case "text":

            if (document.getElementById(curObject).value != document.getElementById(origObject).value) {
                document.getElementById(chngName).value = true;

                document.getElementById('ActionFormChanged').value = true;

                return true;
            }
            break;
        case "input":

            if (document.getElementById(curObject).value != document.getElementById(origObject).value) {
                document.getElementById(chngName).value = true;

                document.getElementById('ActionFormChanged').value = true;

                return true;
            }
            break;
        case "select":


            if (document.getElementById(curObject).value != document.getElementById(origObject).value) {
                document.getElementById(chngName).value = true;

                document.getElementById('ActionFormChanged').value = true;

                return true;
            }
            break;
        case "checkbox":


            if (document.getElementById(curObject).checked.toString() != document.getElementById(origObject).value) {
                document.getElementById(chngName).value = true;

                document.getElementById('ActionFormChanged').value = true;

                return true;
            }
            break;
        default:


            if (document.getElementById(curObject).value != document.getElementById(origObject).value) {

                document.getElementById(chngName).value = true;

                document.getElementById('ActionFormChanged').value = true;

                return true
            }
            break;

    } 
}
return null;
```

}

Comment: If you copied your code word for word you have a problem with your nameArray.

Comment: you are missing a `"` here : `nameArray[4] = "D;`, `it should be nameArray[4] = "D";`